# How to import python modules in AWS Glue script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, python-import, aws-glue

I know regular python library module imports in python while working from a local machine.
Refer the image. At line # 5,6,  both ways of import work correctly. OK. ( Notice the color based underlines for clearer understanding). The connection.py file has just a simple connection class
[image]

The connection.py file has just a simple connection class

[image]

But when I am trying same thing in AWS glue ( pyspark based) such a import isn't working.

```
 from mymath import HelloMsg   
# This works. Glue job completes successfully. 
# In Job Details, I have mentioned the .zip file path in AWS S3 bucket as "python library path".
# That folder is mymath.zip. It has mymath.py file. That file contains a simple HelloMsg class with a method returning Hello msg.
```

AWS GLue job has zip file ref given as per std way
[image]
mymath.zip folder contents :
[image]

```
#mymath2 is another zip file mentioned.  
#It has mymath2.py directly under it and a folder named "Connection"
#which in turn has a simple "connection.py" file

import mymath2   # This also works.  
#But Not clear why above works!. Why? (Question_1)


from mymath2 import HelloMsg  # works # so seems like it doesn't consider .zip folder name. 
#I think above works because mymath2.py file it considers and then internally it does have a hellomsg class so All in all it works 

#But below ways DOnt work.   
import mymath2.Connection  # doesn't work. Why?  (Question_2)
from mymath2.Connection import connection  # doesn't work. Why? (Question_3)
from mymath2 import mymath2  # doesn't work. Why?( Question_4). This should work assuming mymath2 zip file directly has mymath2.py. ( kindly correct if my assumptions are incorrect)
```

Would really appreciate if someone helps.   I have marked places where I have Questions
( Question 1 to 4)

Error msg I get is :
[image]

Also please refer to the mymath2 folder structure for additional clarity.
[image]

Comment: Does your Connection folder contain a __init__.py?

Comment: And could you provide the exact folder structure with the contents of the files?

Comment: Yes Connection folder Does have  __init__.py file ( empty, as we know thats OK )

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error it looks like Glue is expecting mymath2 to be a package, not a module.

A #1 - works as your importing the mymath2 module 
A #2-4 - doesnt work because you're trying to import items from the mymath2 package (the mymath2 directory), not the mymath2 module (the mymath2 file).

My understanding is that a module is simply a py file, while a package can be a collection of modules.

To verify this, you can build a wheel package and reference that from s3 instead of the zip.

To create the wheel write a setp.py file at the root of Misc2 that would look something like:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='Misc2',
    version='0.1',
    packages={
        'mymath2'
    }
)
```

Run the setup script with the following command and upload the resulting whl file (dist/Misc2-0.1-py3-none-any.whl) to s3

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

And then in your code you should be able to import using:

```
import mymath2.Connection
from mymath2.Connection import connection
from mymath2 import mymath2
```

*EDIT*: I just realized that your zip only contains the mymath2 module, and doesn't include the Connections directory. If you don't want to take the wheel approach listed above, you could try to simply include the Connections directory in the zip. I always take the wheel approach as I usually have additional dependencies so can confirm it will work, but you might be able to keep using the zip for this example.

Comment: @Abhijeet - did you ever get the import working?